# How to get the modified details of the SQL through JSP?

Tags: javascript, jsp

After editing the database through jsp, can we get the modified details with old details as well as with date and time?

Comment: We need some more information to really answer your question. If you could post the jsp code, the database code, and the database schema, that'd help a lot.

Comment: To get old database record with date-time,you have to create audit trail for that.